# PHP Image Upload permission issues

Tags: php

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this, and found a lot of articles, but none of them have helped at all. So I ask for everyone's help here.

I'm using GoDaddy's Windows Web Hosting

Here's the error I get when I upload an image:

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(../uploads/aczbyfeoghtmduikwxjrlnvqsp3.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in G:\PleskVhosts\minebloxmc.net\httpdocs\web\upload.php on line 48

PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php27A2.tmp' to '../uploads/aczbyfeoghtmduikwxjrlnvqsp3.jpg' in G:\PleskVhosts\minebloxmc.net\httpdocs\web\upload.php on line 48
```

And here's my code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$target_dir = "../uploads/";

$str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$shuffled = str_shuffle($str);

$target_file = $target_dir . $shuffled . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "PNG" && $imageFileType != "JPEG"
&& $imageFileType != "GIF" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        echo '<br>';

        $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','sutdenlol1');

    if(!$con){
        echo 'Not Connected to Server';
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'mineblox')){
        echo 'Not Selecting Database';
    }


        $sql = "UPDATE users 
    SET Profilepic='$target_file' WHERE ID = ". $_SESSION['id'] ." ";

    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        echo 'Not Inserted';
    } else {
        echo 'Inserted';
    }


    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

echo '<br>';
echo '<img src="../uploads'.$target_file.'"/>';

?>
```

Comment: check the permission for `uploads` folder. It has to have `write` permission

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned this is a Windows server, So you need to set permissions through the GoDaddy permissions panel. You need to set read/write permissions for uploads directory.

Important : Setting 777 by FTP doesn't cut it on Windows servers.

You can set different directory permissions for each of the directories in your Windows® Hosting account, besides the root directory. This lets you control who can access your files and which actions they can perform on files in those directories.

1. Log in to your GoDaddy account.
2. Click **Web Hosting**.
3. Next to the hosting account you want to use, click **Manage**.
4. From the **Tools** section, click **FTP File Manager**.
5. Select the directory  for which you'd like to set permissions.
6. Click 

   **Privacy**

   .
7. Select the permissions you want to use:
8. Click **OK**.

   - **Web visible** — Directory contents are visible to users.
   - **Web writable** — Applications can write to this directory.
   - **Inherit** — Inherit permissions from parent directory. You must deselect this option if you want to select permissions on a per-directory basis.
   - **Set all subfolders to inherit permissions**  — Changes all subfolders to inherit permissions from this folder.

https://uk.godaddy.com/help/set-directory-permissions-windows-6481

Comment: Problem is, I don't know how to do that, there isn't a section called Tools

Comment: I added some more info, and there is a useful link.